# how to use inarray and then use json array which converted into array

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="p1">


      <button type="button">
        b1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="p2">


      <button type="button" >
        b2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="p3">


      <button type="button" >
        b3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- -->

  <div >
    <div id="G1" >

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g2" >

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g3" >

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div >
    <div id="G9">


    </div>
    <div id="G7" >

    </div>
    <div id="G4" >


    </div>

  <div >
    <div id="G5" >


    </div>
    <div id="G6" >

    </div>
    <div id="G3" >

    </div>
  </div>
```

Can I use inarray and then use json array which converted into array  and use nested loop on those created array to show and hide.json converted data.I solved the problem thanks.allows you to have your JavaScript code before the body of your document, in the head section.

Comment: Identify using this variable...Read more https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/559415439113cb37820000a8

Comment: you mean the ... you want to identify one of the `<div class="profile-image">` ... within a css rule? within a javascript code? Your question is not clear enough... what do you mean with a tick mark notation?

Comment: Thanks @Santhosh kumar for this help

Comment: question is not very clear.. can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fa-check").hide();
  $(".z").click(function() {
    $(".fa-check").hide();
    $(this).find(".fa-check").show();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="p1" class="z">
            <i class="fa fa-check" ></i>
            
           
            <div >
                <button type="button"  class="z1">
                  
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="p2" class="z">
             <i class="fa fa-check" ></i>
             
             <div >
                 <button type="button" class="z2">
                     Married, No Kids
                 </button>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div id="p3" class="z">
             <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
             
             <div >
                 <button type="button" id="z3">
                     Happy Family
                 </button>
             </div>
         </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want dynamically hide respective p_check id.I used .check
 {
     display:none;
 }                                      this css to hide tick But when any profile is not selected I want to hide those p_check tick

Comment: Can you run code snippet in my answer and check if that is what you want?

Comment: thanks Sandeep Nayak my problem solved when i used your way but by using addclass and remove class